# DBUnit error : NoSuchTableException

Tags: spring-boot, one-to-many, many-to-one, dbunit, spring-test-dbunit

I tried to write Unit tests for my database Services according to this example (https://github.com/21decemb/spring-boot-dbunit-example). I created dataset and test example. After I run the test I recived: **org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException: orders**

dataset.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>

<!-- CUSTOMER DATA -->
<customers id="1" name="Customer" active="1"/>

<!-- POSITION DATA -->
<positions id="1" name="POSITION1"/>
<positions id="2" name="POSITION2"/>
<positions id="3" name="POSITION3"/>


<!-- ORDER DATA -->
<orders id="1" name="order1" color="RED"  express="0" date="2016-12-11 19:47:39" last_update="2016-12-11 19:47:39" parent_id="1" active="1"/>
 <!--<orders id="2" name="order2" color="WHITE" customer_id="1" position_id="1"  express="0" date="2016-12-11 19:47:39" last_update="2016-12-11 19:47:39" active="0"/>-->


</dataset>
```

The second Order Row is commented becacuse I was testing two possibilities. I know that this is because of joins. When I test only 'positions' and 'customers' (simple entities without joins) it works correctly.

My "Order" entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders", schema = Config.dbSchema)
public class Order implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="POSITION_ID")
    private Position position;

    private short express;

    private Date date;

    @Column(name="LAST_UPDATE")
    private Date lastUpdate;

    @Column(name="parent_id")
    private Long parentId;

    private short active;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_ID")
    private Customer customer;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Component> components; 

    //getters and setters

}
```

Have anyone any idea on how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this property in the override method **setUpDatabaseConfig**:

```
@Override
protected void setUpDatabaseConfig(DatabaseConfig config) {
     config.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_QUALIFIED_TABLE_NAMES, true);
}
```

In addition probably you need to add the schema name like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>

<!-- CUSTOMER DATA -->
<schemaName customers id="1" name="Customer" active="1"/>

<!-- POSITION DATA -->
<schemaName positions id="1" name="POSITION1"/>
<schemaName positions id="2" name="POSITION2"/>
<schemaName positions id="3" name="POSITION3"/>

<!-- ORDER DATA -->
<schemaName orders id="1" name="order1" color="RED"  express="0" date="2016-12-11   19:47:39" last_update="2016-12-11 19:47:39" parent_id="1" active="1"/>
<!--<schemaName orders id="2" name="order2" color="WHITE" customer_id="1" position_id="1"  express="0" date="2016-12-11 19:47:39" last_update="2016-12-11 19:47:39" active="0"/>-->


</dataset>
```